# can i change jquery-ui datepicker html output to display all days of a month in a row

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

is there a way to use jquery-ui datepicker to display all days of one month in one row?

- either by placing all 28-31 `<td>` s in one `<tr>`
- or by completely replacing `<table>` markup with nested `<div>`s that can then be styled/floated via css

this is an example of how it should look like on desktop: http://english.komische-oper-berlin.de/schedule/ (all days of a month in one row)

on smaller screens i would go back to the default month view .. one week per row

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Is it important for mobile page?

Comment: yes. that way i could display all days of a month in one row on desktop while floating weekwise on smaller screens. 
i am aware that there are other solutions like using http://tympanus.net/Development/Calendario/ but i would like to stick to datepicker

Comment: Is something like [this](http://jqueryscript.nhavungtau.vn/demo/iOS-7-Style-jQuery-3D-Animated-Value-Selector-Drumjs/examples) what you need?

Comment: @MaxZoom: i updated my question - see link for visual example